# Why can the maxparallelism of a flink job not be updated without losing state?

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I just read that the maximum parallelism (defined by setMaxParallelism) of a Flink job cannot be changed without losing state. This surprised me a bit, and it is not that hard to imagine a scenario where one starts running a job, only to find out the load is eventually 10x larger than expected (or perhaps the efficiency of the code is below expectations) resulting in a desire to increase parallelism.

I could not find many reasons for this, other than some references to key groups. The most tangible statement I found [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/1988):

> The max parallelism mustn't change when scaling the job, because it would destroy the mapping of keys to key groups.

However, this still leaves me with the questions:

## Why is it hard/impossible to let a job change its max paralellism?

---

Based on the above, the following conceptual solution came to mind:

1. In the state, keep track of the *last used max parallelism*
2. When starting a job, indicate the *desired max parallelism*
3. Given that both settings are known, it should be possible to infer how the mappings would need to change to remain valid initially.
4. If needed a new state could be defined based on the old state with the new maxparallelism, to 'fit' the new job.

I am not saying this conceptual solution is ideal, or that it would be trivial to implement. I just wonder if there is more to the very rigid nature of the maximum parallelism. And trying to understand whether it is just a matter of 'this flexibility is not implemented yet' or 'this goes so much against the nature of Flink that one should not want it'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every key is assigned to exactly one key group by computing a hash of the key modulo the number of key groups. So changing the number of key groups affects the assignment of keys to key groups. Each task manager is responsible for one or more key groups, so the number of key groups is the same as the maximum parallelism.

The reason this number is painful to change is that it is effectively baked into the state snapshots (checkpoints and savepoints). These snapshots are indexed by key group, so that on system start-up, each task manager can efficiently load just the state they require.

There is are in-memory data structures that scale up significantly as the number of key groups rises, which is why the max parallelism doesn't default to some rather large value (the default is 128).

The [State Processor API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html) can be used to rewrite state snapshots, should you need to change the number of key groups, or migrate between state backends.

Comment: So, suppose you desired to change the max parallelism. Do I interpret correctly one would be able to create a save point, update it with the State Processing API to change the max parallelism, and continue from there? (perhaps with some downtime or catching up)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70185813/2000823 for more info.