# Is it possible to change maxParallelism of flink existing job while maintaining state? If yes, can supporting links on 'how to' be shared?

Tags: apache-flink

How can I change the maxParallelism value of an existing flink job without losing the state?

I could see two similar links on this.

1. [Why can the maxparallelism of a flink job not be updated without losing state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627181/why-can-the-maxparallelism-of-a-flink-job-not-be-updated-without-losing-state)
2. [how to increase max parallelism in any condition in flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183583/how-to-increase-max-parallelism-in-any-condition-in-flink)

In the first link, is there any update to the answer David that you gave on this thread. I have the same requirement to changing the maxParallelism of a deployed flink job on production. I cannot afford to lose the state and have restore with the last checkpoint in case of any redeployment. How can I change the maxParallelism value as well as maintain the state and all old information from it? Also is StateProcessor APIs now updated enough for this use-case if yes, is the procedure to do this to a production job complex? And any supporting links on how it is done? Will highly appreciate if you could respond to these queries, or anyone else who has an idea.
Thanks.

Trying to change maxParallelism but it is not possible while restoring from checkpoints.
This is production deployed job and all information is saved in state and that cannot be lost.

Comment: I've updated the answers and comments you linked to above. Support for DataStream windows was added a couple of years ago -- no problem there -- but you could run into issues with the CEP library or the Table API (or maybe not, I'm not sure). I also provided links to a related example that may help you get started.